# Lidar Data augmentation

Tags: python, deep-learning

I am working on Object Segmentation using Lidar 3D point clouds, basically using Kitti dataset. However, the dataset is imbalanced for classes cyclists and pedestrians. So, I am looking for ways to

```
1. Augment the point clouds to increase the dataset size for more instances of pedestrians and cyclists and 
2. To create an unbiased model which is more accurate and robust
```

Can someone guide me as to how can I do it for point clouds, like augmentation techniques (apart from flipping in horizontal direction) or adding some kind of noise(awgn)/distortion to point clouds, while preserving the data consistency?